# About simulating Jquery selector method

Tags: javascript, jquery

while typting  `$("div")` there's an array like `[<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>]` which
gets a bunch of method from `jQuery.fn`,I'm interested in simulating it,but I can't make it "smooth"
I refered zepto.js:

```
  zepto.Z = function(dom, selector) {
    dom = dom || []
    dom.__proto__ = arguments.callee.prototype
    dom.selector = selector || ''
    return dom
  }
```

But since it's not cross-browser,I wrote some snippets as following:

```
var query=function(selector){    
  return new query.init(selector);    
};
query.init=function(selector){
   var found=document.querySelectorAll(selector);
   this.length=found.length;
   for(var i=0,len=this.length;i<len;i++){
     this[i]=found[i];
    }
  return this;
};
query.init.prototype={
  method1:function(){},
  method2:function(){}
}
```

while typing `query("#id")`,alough it can manipulate functionally,but it doesn't seem well enough
[image]
as you can see,how to write a query function that looks like jQuery?Thanks

Comment: Why do you not want to use the original jQuery in the first place?

Comment: academic purpose,just want to learn more about how it works

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with something simple like:

```
function MaterObject(selector) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Now add functionality through MasterObject.prototype:

```
MasterObject.prototype = {
  getLength: function() {
    return this.elements.length;
  },

  refresh: function() {
    this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
    return this;
   },

  addMore: function(selector) {
    this.selector = this.selector + ',' + selector;
    this.refresh();
    return this;
   }
}
```

and so on. To kick it off:

```
function $(selector) {
  return new MasterObject(selector);
}
```

The above lacks feature testing so is brittle.

Note that much of jQuery is overloaded so it needs to test what it's been given, then decide to do with the results (the famous case of "isArray" comes to mind). Calling a method might do something to all the elements selected by the selector, or just the first one. Passing a method a string, object or nothing may completely change what the method does.

Note that functions can return `this` so methods can be chained. The problem though (for both the library designer and the user) is working out which ones should be chainable and which shouldn't, e.g.

```
var $x = $('div');

// addMore is chainable, getLength isn't
$x.addMore('p').getLength();
```

#### Edit

If you want your "jQuery" object to be an array, then you'll have to add all methods to be inherited to Array.prototype, which is not such a good idea. There is no other way, you can't create an array object and insert your own prototype object into its `[[Prototype]]` chain, an array instance will inherit directly from Array.prototype.

The best you can do is convert the elements NodeList to an array (as you do in the OP) and call array-like methods on it  (noting that as a result, the selector may not represent the contents of the elements array):

```
function MasterObject(selector) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.elements = [];
}

MasterObject.prototype = {
  ...

  refresh: function() {
    this.elements = [];
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
    for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      this.elements[i] = els[i];
    }
    return this;
  },

  pop: function() {
    return this.elements.pop();
  },
```

Perphaps such changes should be reflected in the DOM (in this case the selector should be in sync with the contents without having to select it again via qSA):

```
  popElement: function() {
    var el = this.elements.pop();
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    return el;
  },

  ...
};

function $(selector) {
  var newObj = new MasterObject(selector); 
  newObj.refresh();
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks RobG,I know how chainable work,my question is ,how to make my query function return an array that has some methods like method1,method2,thanks a lot~

Comment: Oh, the object returned by jQuery isn't an array, it's a plain object. jQuery adds numeric properties to it so `0` references the first element, `1` the second and so on. It also adds some array methods to it (`push` and `slice` at least)—which makes for some handy ways to create some very obscure bugs if you're willing. :-)